# How to filter the images shown on the PHPickerViewController to those selected for limited access

Tags: swift, xcode, phphotolibrary, ios14.5

How do I filter the images shown on the PHPickerViewController to those that have been selected under limited access by the user? Or do I need to use a different picker? I've been struggling with this for a few days now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

When user taps the button:
1-5 are automatic

1. The alert appears with Camera or Photo Library
2. They choose Photo Library
3. The authorization alert appears with Select Photo…, Allow Access to All Photos or Don’t Allow
4. They tap Select Photos = .limited
5. The presentLimitedLibraryPicker is displayed, for the user to choose the photos thay want to allow and taps Done.
6. Now I want the picker to appear with a filtered choice of the images the user has just chosen. Seems like this would be automatic too. Not...

This only displays the same picker where the user made the selections for limited access.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker(from: self)
```

What goes in the .limited case?

```
var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
config.selectionLimit = 1
config.filter = PHPickerFilter.any(of: [.images, .livePhotos])
let picker_Photo = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
picker_Photo.delegate = self

let libCell = UIAction(title: "Photo Library", image: UIImage(systemName: "photo"), identifier: .none, discoverabilityTitle: .none) { (libAction) in
                
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary)
    {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .readWrite) { status in
            
            switch status
            {
            case .limited:
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    // PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)
                    // PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker
                    self.present(picker_Photo, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                
            case .authorized:
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    self.present(picker_Photo, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                
            case .notDetermined:
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    self.present(picker_Photo, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                
            case .restricted:
                self.view.sendConfirmationAlert(theTitle: "Photo Library Restricted",
                                                theMessage: "Photo Library access was previously denied. Please update your Settings to allow access.", buttonTitle: "Ok")
                
            case .denied:
                let settingsAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Library Access Denied",
                                                      message: "Photo Library access was previously denied. Please update your Settings to allow access.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                
                let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Settings", style: .default) { ( action ) in
                    let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)
                    UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl!, options: [:])
                }
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    settingsAlert.addAction(settingsAction)
                    settingsAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
                    self.present(settingsAlert, animated: true)
                }
                
            default:
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken about what limited access means. It restricts what information you can read and write into *the photo library*.

But your code does *not* read from the photo library in the first place. You are saying

```
config = PHPickerConfiguration()
```

So this means you have *no photo library access at all* by way of the picker. You can only get image copies. You therefore do not need *any* kind of permission to show the picker, and the user limitation makes *no difference* to you. You can in fact just throw away all your authorization related code; it has no effect. Your picker will work exactly the same without it.

If you needed photo library access by way of the picker, you would have called

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerconfiguration/3616114-init

In that case the user limitation *would* matter to you — when you tried to access an actual PHAsset. But your code never does that. You are asking for a permission you do not need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought limited access meant the access the user is allowing the app to have to their photo library.

Comment: Yes but you are not accessing the photo library.

Comment: Just for clarity incase someone wants to answer my question. What I posted was not the complete code, only the part relevant to my question. I do need read access to the photo library so the user can bring photos into the app.  So I need to request access first.

Comment: But my answer stands. The nature of the authorization from the user, or lack of it, has no effect on the behavior of your picker. You are confusing two different things.

Comment: Might help to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picking-a-photo-in-ios-14/

Comment: Finally: if you really have a goal to present a picker listing only the images to which the user has provided access, then you will have to track what images those are (ios 15 lets you do that) and write your own picker.